How to add js codes to newly added list items
uhmn, I created an unordered list with a js code running on each of the list items but when I add new list items with an input tag, the code does not affect them.
I tried looping through the list to get each items individually and add the code to both the previous items and the newly added ones but the code was only added to the previous list items neglecting the new ones.
let ul= document.getElementsByClassName("ul")[0];
let list= ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

function listLength() {
  return list.length;
};

for (let i=0; i<listLength(); i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener("click", toggleList);
  function toggleList() {
    return list[i].classList.toggle("done");
  };
};


Use event delegation instead of adding a listener to each item.
